# Ifelse Statement to Replace Value in Corresponding Row

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe like below:

```
 Col1     Col2     COl4    Col5
   A         B       NA      NA
   M         L       NA      lo
   A         N       NA      KE
```

How do I make the logic where, if Col1 = A, replace NA in COl4 with "Pass"?

When I try using ifelse, I do not get the expected output.

Expected output should be:

```
 Col1     Col2     COl4    Col5
   A         B     Pass      NA
   M         L       NA      lo
   A         N     Pass      KE
```

I tried this but no luck:

```
df$COl4<-
  ifelse(df$Col1=="A", "Pass", df$COl4)
```

Comment: df$COl4<- ifelse(df$Col1=="A" & is.na(df$COl4), "Pass", df$COl4)

Comment: Your code looks like it should work given the example data. What does "no luck" mean - an error, a warning, no change to the data ?

Comment: A lot easier to just do `df$COl4[df$Col1 == "A"] <- "Pass"`

Comment: @RichScriven that worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No real need for `ifelse()` here.  You can use standard index replacement.

```
df$COl4[df$Col1 == "A"] <- "Pass"
```

This says that we are replacing `COl4` such that `Col1 == "A"` with `"Pass"`.  Additionally, this method will not mess with attributes like `ifelse()` will.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)

tab <- tibble(Col1 = c("A", "M", "A"), Col2 = c("B", "L", "N"), COl4 = c(NA, NA, NA), Col5 = c(NA, "lo", "KE"))

tab %>%
  mutate(COl4 = case_when(
    Col1 == "A" ~ "Pass",
    TRUE ~ as.character(COl4))
  )
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Col1  Col2  COl4  Col5 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     B     Pass  NA   
2 M     L     NA    lo   
3 A     N     Pass  KE
```

The benefit of using `case_when` is when you have too many conditions.

The `TRUE` is for the rest of the COl4 that doesn't need any condition).